# Objectmendername with Spaces

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a CSV-List to replace Strings in an XML.

Now the CSV looks like:

```
First;Secound One; Third 
Name;Beschreibung Neu;Func1 
Number;handout her, func2
```

The Code is:

```
#Splatennamen auslesen
$CSVSpalten = $CSVData | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'


# xml Objekt erstellen
$xml = New-Object XML
# xml laden
$xml.Load($OPN_in)

# Abfrage des ersten 'SW.Blocks.CompileUnit' Knotens
$Bsp_NW = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//SW.Blocks.CompileUnit")


# abbrechen wenn kein Knoten gefunden wurde.
if (!$Bsp_NW){
    throw "Error, 'SW.Blocks.CompileUnit' Node not found!"
    exit 1
}

$z=0
foreach($Zeile in $CSV_reseve)
{

    # erstelle eine Kopie des Knotens im Speicher
    $NEU_NW = $Bsp_NW.Clone()

    #Texte Ersetzen 
    foreach($spalte in $CSVSpalten)
        {
        #$NEU_NW.innerxml
        write-Host "ALt: $spalte  NEU: $Zeile.$spalte " 
        $NEU_NW.innerxml = $NEU_NW.innerxml -replace ("$spalte" -replace "'"),($Zeile."$spalte" -replace "'")

        #ID's verändern
        $z+=1
        $NEU_NW.innerxml = $NEU_NW.innerxml.Replace(' ID="',' ID="'+($z*10).ToString())
        #>
    }
    # id anpassen
    $NEU_NW.Id = (100*$z).ToString()

    # hänge den kopierten Knoten im selben Parent wie vom Original wieder ins XML ein
    $Bsp_NW.ParentNode.InsertAfter($NEU_NW,$Bsp_NW)
}
```

Problem is the row:

```
$NEU_NW.innerxml = $NEU_NW.innerxml -replace ("$spalte" -replace "'"),($Zeile."$spalte" -replace "'")
```

I think its because the Space in the Name of the 2. Colum and the Uses in -> $Zeile."$spalte" <-.

How can is Correct it?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the original Al xml document in your question? Can you also show the “incorrect” result and what you’d like to happen instead? It’s hard to make any suggestions without knowing this information…

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line, as yours is a odd way to deal with the csv import.

$***CSVData= import-csv $CSVFile -encoding -utf8 -delimiter ';'***

If it still does not work, then try using this to modify the $spalte before the replace.

***[string]$Spalte2 = $Spalte -replace "'"***

***$NEU_NW.innerxml = [string]$NEU_NW.innerxml -replace $spalte2,$Zeile.$Spalte2***

See if removing the -replace sorts things.

Comment: added [string] to the $NEU_NW.innerxml, to force it to be string (text).;

Answer (score 0):

XML-DATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <Engineering version="V18" />
   <SW.Blocks.FB ID="0">
    <AttributeList>
      <Interface><Sections xmlns="http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/Interface/v5">
   <Section Name="Static">
    <Member Name="C_SFC3600" Datatype="&quot;Control_SFC&quot;" Accessibility="Public">
      <AttributeList>
        <BooleanAttribute Name="ExternalAccessible" SystemDefined="true">true</BooleanAttribute>
      </AttributeList>
    </Member>
  </Section>
  <Section Name="Temp" />
  <Section Name="Constant" />
</Sections></Interface>

    </AttributeList>
    <ObjectList>
      <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="3" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
        <AttributeList>
  <Parts>
    <Access Scope="LiteralConstant" UId="21">
      <Constant>
        <ConstantType>UInt</ConstantType>
        <ConstantValue>990</ConstantValue>
        <StringAttribute Name="Format" Informative="true">Dec_unsigned</StringAttribute>
      </Constant>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="22">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="UDT_SFC" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="128" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="23">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="Quittieren" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="376" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="24">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="Auto" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="328" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="25">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="Hand_mit_Trans" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="360" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="26">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="Hand_ohne_Trans" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="368" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="27">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="iHand" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="320" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="28">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="Schrittnummer Soll" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="UInt" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="176" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="29">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XBef" />
        <Component Name="H_Nächster_Schritt" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="384" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="30">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="Schrittnummer IST" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="UInt" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="160" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="31">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="Transition_OK" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="312" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="32">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="Störung" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="248" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="33">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="Auto(0=Hand; 1=Auto))" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="208" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="34">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="Hand_mit_Trans" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="216" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="35">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="Hand_ohne_Trans" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="224" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Access Scope="GlobalVariable" UId="36">
      <Symbol>
        <Component Name="SFC360" />
        <Component Name="_0" />
        <Component Name="Daten" />
        <Component Name="XSta" />
        <Component Name="iHand" />
        <Address Area="None" Type="Bool" BlockNumber="360" BitOffset="232" Informative="true" />
      </Symbol>
    </Access>
    <Call UId="37">
      <CallInfo Name="Control_SFC" BlockType="FB">
        <IntegerAttribute Name="BlockNumber" Informative="true">997</IntegerAttribute>
        <DateAttribute Name="ParameterModifiedTS" Informative="true">2024-01-16T13:59:43</DateAttribute>
        <Instance Scope="LocalVariable" UId="38">
          <Component Name="C_SFC3600" />
        </Instance>
        <Parameter Name="Abbruch_Start_Schritt" Section="Input" Type="UInt">
          <StringAttribute Name="InterfaceFlags" Informative="true">S7_Visible</StringAttribute>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="Daten" Section="InOut" Type="&quot;UDT_SFC&quot;">
          <StringAttribute Name="InterfaceFlags" Informative="true">S7_Visible</StringAttribute>
        </Parameter>
      </CallInfo>
    </Call>
 </Parts>
</FlgNet></NetworkSource>
          <ProgrammingLanguage>FBD</ProgrammingLanguage>
          <MultilingualText ID="6" CompositionName="Title">
            <ObjectList>
              <MultilingualTextItem ID="7" CompositionName="Items">
                <AttributeList>
                  <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
                  <Text>SFC3600 - Produktion Linie1</Text>
                </AttributeList>
              </MultilingualTextItem>
            </ObjectList>
          </MultilingualText>
        </ObjectList>
      </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>
      <MultilingualText ID="D" CompositionName="Title">
        <ObjectList>
          <MultilingualTextItem ID="E" CompositionName="Items">
            <AttributeList>
              <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
              <Text />
            </AttributeList>
          </MultilingualTextItem>
        </ObjectList>
      </MultilingualText>
    </ObjectList>
  </SW.Blocks.FB>
</Document>
```

CSV:

```
3600;SFC3600 - Produktion Linie1;SFC360._0.Daten
3601;SFC3601 - CIP Linie1;SFC360._1.Daten
3602;SFC3602 - SIP Linie1;SFC360._2.Daten
```

**I'd like to copy the Node [ <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="3" CompositionName="CompileUnits"> ] and change the text "*SFC3600 - Produktion Linie1*" to "*CIP Linie1*" (and "*SFC3602 - SIP Linie1*")**

The full Powershell:

```
Set-Location -path C:\OPN
#Powersehll funktionen importieren
. .\scripte\Functions.ps1
#Array Objektname
$CSVFile = (GetFile -Info "CSV-Datei" -DataType "csv")[1]
$CSVData= GetCsvAsObject($CSVFile)
$OPN_in =(GetFile -Info "FC/FB-FILE")[1]
$CSVName = (Get-Item $CSVFile).BaseName
$OPN_Out="C:\OPN\imp\$CSVName.xml"
$CSVData
## CSV sortierung umdrehen
$CSV_reseve=$CSVData.Clone()
for ($i=1; $i -lt $CSVData.Length; $i++) {
$CSV_reseve[$i]= $CSVData[$CSVData.Length-$i]

}

cls

#Splatennamen auslesen
$CSVSpalten = $CSVData | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'


# xml Objekt erstellen
$xml = New-Object XML
# xml laden
$xml.Load($OPN_in)

# Abfrage des ersten 'SW.Blocks.CompileUnit' Knotens
$Bsp_NW = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//SW.Blocks.CompileUnit")


# abbrechen wenn kein Knoten gefunden wurde.
if (!$Bsp_NW){
    throw "Error, 'SW.Blocks.CompileUnit' Node not found!"
    exit 1
}

$z=0
foreach($Zeile in $CSV_reseve)
{

    # erstelle eine Kopie des Knotens im Speicher
    $NEU_NW = $Bsp_NW.Clone()

    #Texte Ersetzen 
    foreach($spalte in $CSVSpalten)
        {
        #$NEU_NW.innerxml
        write-Host "ALt: $spalte  NEU: $Zeile.$spalte " 
        $NEU_NW.innerxml = $NEU_NW.innerxml -replace ("$spalte" -replace "'"),($Zeile."$spalte" -replace "'")

        #ID's verändern
        $z+=1
        $NEU_NW.innerxml = $NEU_NW.innerxml.Replace(' ID="',' ID="'+($z*10).ToString())
        #>
    }
    # id anpassen
    $NEU_NW.Id = (100*$z).ToString()

    # hänge den kopierten Knoten im selben Parent wie vom Original wieder ins XML ein
    $Bsp_NW.ParentNode.InsertAfter($NEU_NW,$Bsp_NW)
}

#Basisdatenändern
$xml.Document.'SW.Blocks.FB'.AttributeList.Name =[STRING]$CSVName
$xml.Document.'SW.Blocks.FB'.AttributeList.Number = [String]($xml.Document.'SW.Blocks.FB'.AttributeList.Number+'00')


# speichere das geänderte xml unter neuem Namen
$xml.Save($OPN_Out)
#>
```

The Function Powershell:

```
function GetCsvAsObject($CSVPath){
    
if ($CSVPath)
    {

    (Get-Content $CSVPath)|
    ForEach-Object{$_ -replace ';',","}| # simikolon ersetzen
    ForEach-Object{$_ -replace '´t',","}| #Tab ersetzen
    Set-Content $CSVPath -Encoding UTF8
    #Get-Content $CSVPath 
    #Set-Content $CSVPath $CSVText

    return Import-Csv -Path $CSVPath -Delimiter ","
    }


}

function GetFile{
    Param( $path = [STRING]"C:\OPN",
           $Info = [STRING]"XML-FILE",
           $DataType = [STRING]"xml" 

      )

        [void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'System.Windows.Forms' )

        $d = New-Object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog


        $d.InitialDirectory = "C:\OPN"
        $d.Filter = "$Info (*.$DataType)|*.$DataType|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        $d.ShowHelp = $true
        $d.ShowDialog((New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost = $true; TopLevel = $true}))

        return $d.FileName



        }
```

Comment: If I Use "NWName" instead of "SFC3600 - Produktion Linie1" the code works fine.